# Required List parameter 'state' is not present error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am trying to make a select multiple form in thymeleaf.

My controller:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/employer/questionnaire")
public String employerQuestionnaire(@RequestParam Map<String, String> body,
@RequestParam("state") List<String> states, Model model){
questionnaire.setStates(states);
}
```

My template:

```
<label for="State" class="label">State</label>
<select id="State" name="State" data-name="State" class="w-select" 
 multiple="multiple">       
   <option th:each="s : ${states}" th:value="${s.getName()}" 
   th:text="${s.getName()}" th:selected="${questionnaire.getStates() != null 
   && questionnaire.getStates().contains(s.getName())}"></option>
```

I have List of states in my domain and I am trying to set multiple states for the user but I get this error message "Required List parameter 'state' is not present". I think there is something wrong with my controller and the @RequestParam

Comment: There is a parameter `State` not `state`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You indicated that you method is `@PostMapping` so it indicating a post request. `@RequestParam` indicates that the parameter is coming from the url and the error your getting is its not in the url it would be something like

`localhost:8080/myApp/employer/questionnaire?state=Hello`

Try changing the `@RequestParam` to `@RequestBody` as post data is contained in the body of the post.